# Amazon S3 bucket policy for anonymously uploading photos to a bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I am planning on using Amazon S3 to let users upload photos from an iPhone and then let them be publicly viewable.

I am having some trouble understanding how to set up these security constraints in the bucket policy:

- Everyone can read every file.
- Everyone can upload a *new* file that is maximum 256K large.
- No one can delete any file.
- No one can modify any file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I sort of worked it out in the end. The only thing is that you can't set different permissions on adding files and updating files. They are all covered by s3:PutObject. Also, it doesn't seem possible to restrict file size.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "allow-public-read",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        },
    {
            "Sid": "allow-public-put",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        }
  ]
}
```

Comment: so there's no option to set max size restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like the one below will work, but I am not sure you can restrict the upload size.

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
      "Condition": {}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you specify the *Acl actions?