# Amazon S3. Maximum object size

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there a possibility to set maximum file (object) size using a bucket's policy?
I found here a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310462/amazon-s3-bucket-policy-for-anonymously-uploading-photos-to-a-bucket) like this, but there is no size limitation in the examples.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't do this with a bucket policy. Check the [Element Descriptions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#AvailableKeys) page of the S3 documentation for an exhaustive list of the things you can do in a bucket policy.

However, you *can* specify a `content-length-range` restriction within a [Browser Uploads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) policy document. This feature is commonly used for giving untrusted users write access to specific keys within an S3 bucket you control (e.g. user-facing media uploads), and it provides the appropriate tools for limiting the location, size, and data types that can be uploaded without needing to expose your S3 credentials.

Comment: Does this also work for presigned HTTP PUT uploads?