# S3: my multi-part uploader doesn't work for files > 5GB

Tags: ruby, linux, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload many large (30GB+) files to an S3 bucket using the multipart upload feature.

Here is the code. I've put it in a gist to avoid cluttering this page: https://gist.github.com/twslankard/5296081

Files smaller than 5GB are uploaded with no problems. Files larger than 5GB seem to get "clipped" at 5GB, according to the sizes of the objects in the S3 management console.

During the upload, I get no exceptions or error messages of any kind. I also find nothing in the documentation to suggest I'm doing something wrong.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT: I've learned from AWS support that multipart upload is not yet supported in the Ruby SDK**

Comment: I can confirm the Ruby SDK (aws-sdk gem) does support multipart uploads.8

Comment: It does according to the documentation, but it doesn't work past 5GB.

Comment: I just ran a test locally and uploaded a 6GB file without issue.  I suspect you are running into a policy issue with your bucket.

Comment: @TrevorRowe The issue is definitely not a policy issue. It was due to a bug in the AWS SDK for Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to AWS, multipart upload is not supported in the Ruby SDK.

However, I've found a python boto-based multipart uploading script.

https://gist.github.com/chrishamant/1556484

**EDIT**: Ruby SDK now supports multipart upload http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu-ruby-sdk.html

Comment: For those who are curious, I learned about the problem with the Ruby SDK from AWS support.

Answer (score 3):

S3 has a policy document that authorizes the form and imposes limits on the files that can be uploaded. One of the limits is content length. Verbatim from [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434):

> Content length rule, which checks that the size of an uploaded file
>   is between a given minimum and maximum value. **If this rule is not
>   included in a policy document, users will be able to upload files of
>   any size up to the 5GB limit imposed by S3.**

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, it's not clear from the documentation how to apply such a policy programmatically. I've tried adding the content  length rule to the bucket policy, but this is not supported/allowed.

Comment: You can assign the policy to the S3 bucket you're using. Why do you need to assign it pragmatically? Also, try generating the policy using the [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to test that it works as expected.

Comment: I tried using the Policy Generator as well, but there was no way (as far as I could tell) to assign a content length condition. I tried doing so by specifying it in a JSON policy document and applying it via the management console, but I got an error that said this was not allowed.

Comment: The answer to this question corroborates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608567/amazon-s3-maximum-object-size

Comment: Did you try adding this to your form `<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="YOUR_POLICY_DOCUMENT_BASE64_ENCODED">`, as described [here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434)?

Comment: No, because I'm trying to upload via a script rather than a POST form.