# AWS S3 Java SDK: Creating a policy with content-length-range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been using the AWS Java SDK to create policy documents (as opposed to creating the policy JSON directly). I've been able to create a basic policy that has key prefix requirements, but I can't figure out how to build in file size requirements. I've seen this come through as a JSON array in samples:

```
['content-length-range', 0, 1024]
```

But I can't seem to be able to do this programmatically, with the Java SDK. Browsing through the classes and docs don't seem to give a good hint either.

Is anyone doing this currently? What does the code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like what I want to do can't be done (the condition keys don't exist for it). There is a different type of policy called a Browser Upload policy that can have this type of condition though. Link below:

[Amazon S3. Maximum object size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608567/amazon-s3-maximum-object-size)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [NumericCondition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/policy/conditions/NumericCondition.html) class for adding the desired conditions to your [s3 policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html).

For example, you could use a policy like this:

```
    Policy policy = new Policy().withStatements(
        new Statement(Effect.Allow)
        .withActions(S3Actions.PutObject)
        .withResources(new Resource("arn:aws:s3:::foo_bucket"))
        .withConditions(
            new NumericCondition(NumericComparisonType.NumericLessThanEquals, "s3:content-length-range", "1024"),
            new NumericCondition(NumericComparisonType.NumericGreaterThan, "s3:content-length-range", "0")
        )
    );
```

Note that you need to prefix the key (*content-length-range*) with `s3:` to construct a valid policy.

The policy generated from the code above looks like this, in Json:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::foo_bucket"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "NumericGreaterThan": {
          "s3:content-length-range": [
            "0"
          ]
        },
        "NumericLessThanEquals": {
          "s3:content-length-range": [
            "1024"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me - looks like its simply not supported.

Comment: See the question I linked to in my answer. There are apparently two different types of S3 policies. There is the regular "Bucket Policy", but then there is a "Browser Upload Policy". As far as I can tell, only the Browser Upload Policy doc allows you to restrict content length.

Comment: The above condition does not work. This error, "Policy has an invalid condition key - s3:content-length-range", shows after you put in the bucket policy editor.