# Can I limit the size of an object put into S3 via the JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

It is possible to use JavaScript APIs to upload objects to S3 and it is possible to have a fine-grain authorization using IAM policies. For instance, see this policy:

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    },
  ]
}
```

inspired from their [tutorial](http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/) which allows to put objects into the bucket `YOUR_BUCKET_NAME`. However it is not clear to me whether it is possible to limit the number of objects and the size of each objects one can upload. I have checked into the list of [contitions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html), but I didn't find anything useful on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible to limit the number of objects and the size of each object one can upload to S3? In general, no. You cannot do this through any kind of bucket policy.

You can, however, limit an individual object upload size from browsers using a pre-signed POST URL with a [policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) indicating a `content-length-range`.

Alternatively, you could code this restriction into your JS client or a server that proxies your uploads.

See [JS examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html) and a [discussion of policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html) and a related response on [restricting object size via POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608567/amazon-s3-maximum-object-size).

Comment: 1 and 2 where not really questions, but what I had learned in my study.

Comment: 3. is the real question: having such a control server-side or client-side would undermine the whole idea of building a server-less infrastructure. How could I trust that the client does not turn my S3 bucket into a free unlimited remote hard drive?

Comment: @DavideVernizzi I'm not aware of a trivial S3 bucket configuration solution here but you could easily use Lambda. You could write a simple Lambda function that detected new objects over a certain size and deleted them. It could also do the same if the number of objects in the bucket were too high. This would still fit into your model of serverless infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

In reply to the title "Can I limit the size of an object put into S3 via the JavaScript API?"

Yes you can. But instead of using IAM, use [createPresignedPost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property). In `Conditions` specify a maximum [content-length-range](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-PolicyConditions).