# public-ish write access to S3 bucket with file size limiting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-lambda

I would like to provide a public-ish write access to an S3 bucket, but with the option to limit the upload size.

Enabling public write access to the bucket via bucket policies is not enough, because there's no such [s3 condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#object-keys-in-amazon-s3-policies) to limit the upload size.

Another recommended solution is to use signed [POST policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html), which has `content-length-range`, but I cannot use this directly, because the policy requires an expiretaion date, which will obviously change for each request. I cannot deploy the (desktop) application with actual credentials, which means I cannot sign the policies.

After further study I see the following options:

- **a)** create a lambda endpoint **to which I upload the file**

  The lambda function would verify the file size, and copy the file to S3 bucket. The file size limit is small (~MBs at most), so lambda execution time limit shouldn't be a problem.
- **b)** create a lambda endpoint that **generates signed POST policy**

  Uploading file would then result in two requests: (1) make a GET request to get a new signed policy, and (2) upload file directly to S3 using the retrieved policy.
- **c)** create a lambda endpoint that **generates pre-signed URLs**

  Pretty much same as b).

**Questions**:

- What would be the recommended way to approach / what are the pros/cons of each approach?
- Is there a practical difference between using signed POST policies and pre-signed URLs? Especially considering the pre-signed URL uses the same POST policy anyway.

Comment: POST policy require the user to have IAM credentials. Using pre-signed URL’s you can share that URL with any user who does not have IAM credentials and they can upload/download files. So e.g. if you wanted your customer to upload a file to your S3 bucket but do not want to create an AWS IAM user. You could generate a pre-signed URL as suppose to a POST policy which need a IAM credential.

Comment: see also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31419311/119861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I decided to go with **pre-signed POSTs** and reject the other two for the following reasons:

- **a) lambda upload:** I already wanted something that was provided by S3 API natively, so I would have to implement all the validation by myself, which is both potential source of problems, and a long-term extra maintenance, especially if I were to choose different API. Nevertheless if there was some really complex validation scenario that cannot be expressed with declarative conditions, this would have to be the way to go.
- **c) pre-signed URL:** In principle this is identical to pre-signed POST with one major difference: It cannot be debugged. The pre-signed URL no longer contains policy information. So whether I would make a mistake, or I would break the conditions the result would be the same: the signature of the data provided wouldn't match the pre-signed one and so it would just fail and I wouldn't be any wiser as to why.

With **pre-signed POST** I always receive the actual reason for failure -- whether it is missing/extra key or condition mismatch, which is useful both from debugging perspective, as well as processing one -- I can react to each situation differently. (Note that if I wanted to hide the information from users, pre-signed URL could be considered, of course at the cost of debugging/processing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the content length in Presigned post,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html

Looks for `Specifying Ranges`

We have solved by using lambda which generates pre-signed url for the post.

> Browser -- Lambda (PreSignedPost) -- Browser -- Post it to S3

If the length range (between minimum and maximum) does not match post will fail.

Hope it helps.