# Dynamic usage of AWS S3

Tags: web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I trying to explore AWS S3 and I found out that we can store data and have a URL for a file which can be used on a website, but my intention is to store files on S3 and have users of my website post and retrieve files to/from S3 without my intervention. I am trying to have my server and JSP/Servlets pages on EC2 on which Tomcat (and MySQL server) will be running.
Is this possible and if yes, how can i achieve this.

Thanks,
SD

Comment: I think this might be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310462/amazon-s3-bucket-policy-for-anonymously-uploading-photos-to-a-bucket

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. A full answer to this question is tantamount to a consulting gig, but some resources that should get you started:

- [The S3 API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html)
- [Elastic Beanstalk for your webtier](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html)
- [Amazon RDS for MySQL](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/GettingStartedGuide/Welcome.html)

Comment: HI, thanks for the links. can you suggest some video tutorials to get me started? I am totally new to this and  find the AWS forums a little overwhelming.

Comment: @user1652930 Afraid I can't. There might be some out there but I can't stand video tutorials personally and thus never remember them when I see them.