# Image Uploading on Production fails to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-s3, passenger, carrierwave

I am using a Digital Ocean Droplet with Nginx + Passenger as the server. We are using CarrierWave gem in Rails to upload the Images and Resize/Process and upload it to Amazon S3. It works perfectly fine in the Local Environment but when i deploy it to the the Production the Image Uploading does not work.

Error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

The App is running at port `80`

Not sure where to look at to even Debug the Issue. Passenger Logs doesnt show any error for the same either.

Comment: You can see logs into nginx. For access log you can check into '/var/log/nginx/access.log' or for error log you can check into '/var/log/nginx/error.log'

Answer (score 2):

You can see logs into nginx.

For access log you can check into '/var/log/nginx/access.log' 
   or 
For error log you can check into '/var/log/nginx/error.log'

Let me know if you need me more.

Comment: there is nothing in the logs as well. any idea how i can debug to know the issues?

Comment: For debug you can configure http://www.oohlalog.com/ in your application and you will check out production log over here and it is easy to configure as well

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look in the S3 logs as well. Or in the network tab of your browser (enable preserve log). There has to be an error somewhere ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your IAM user policies? Make sure you are using a IAM user instead of the root AWS user/key, for s3 upload. Here is an example of a policy to allow anonymous upload to your bucket. Surely you don't want anonymous upload, this is just as an example policy, perhaps your policy requirements may be more restrictive.

[Amazon S3 bucket policy for anonymously uploading photos to a bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310462/amazon-s3-bucket-policy-for-anonymously-uploading-photos-to-a-bucket)